# Group all similiar text into different groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with text in it, I want to somehow distinguish in different groups those text that can be found by a LIKE query. So for example I have

```
blabla
a1aaaa
bla
lab
aaa
a1
c25
```

I want to get the following result or something similar that I will be able to use easily in my script.

```
blabla 1
bla    1
lab     1
a1aaaa 2
aaa    2
a1     2
c25    3
```

Here is the situation

```
bla IS NOT LIKE '%blabla%'
lab IS NOT LIKE '%blabla%'
blabla IS LIKE '%bla%' So it should go into one group
lab IS NOT LIKE '%bla'
blabla IS LIKE '%lab' Lab should be added to the first created group
```

Basically I want to group similar words to different groups

Comment: I don't understand your question. For example, why do you want `3` for `c25` ? Oh, I'm starting to understand...

Comment: @JérômeRadix maybe you can explain because I still don't understand how c25 got 3?

Comment: In addition to that, 'blabla' is like 'bla' and 'lab' so why is its number not two?

Comment: 1, 2, 3 are in fact the name of the groups (they are not a count of something). For each element in the table, he/she wants to check if it is LIKE or NOT LIKE each other elements and group them under the same group name.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.text_col AS `group_name`, 
    B.text_col AS `member`
FROM
    text_table AS A
    INNER JOIN text_table AS B
        ON A.text_col LIKE concat( '%', B.text_col, '%')
```

Basing on your example data, it should give you:

```
group_name |  member
-------------------------------------
blabla        blabla 
blabla        bla 
blabla        lab 
a1aaaa        a1aaaa
a1aaaa        aaa 
a1aaaa        a1  
c25           c25
```

I hope it could occur helpful.